# Adding additional classes in stanford NLP NER

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

For stanford NER 3 class model, Location, Person, Organization recognizers are available. Is it possible to add additional classes to this model. For example : Sports as one class to tag sports names.

or if not, is there any model where i can add additional classes.

Note: I didnt exactly mean to add "sports" as a class. I was wondering is there a possibility to add a custom class in that model. If not possible in stanford, is it possible with spacy..

Answer (score 0):

Sports doesn't really fall into the Entity category, as there are a limited number of them, and they are pretty fixed, unlike the names of people or locations, so you can list them all.

I would simply set up a list of sports names, and use string matching to find them.

Comment: I didnt exactly mean to add sports as a class. I was wondering is there a possibility to add a custom class in that model. If not in stanford, is it possible with spacy